# Checking if any file exist, but not directory, in a batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have following directory structure.

```
dir1
dir1\subdir
backup
```

And I want to move files under dir1, but not subdir, to backup directory.

```
if exist dir1\*.* move dir1\*.* backup
```

If there's any files under dir1, then the script runs fine, but if dir1 is empty, then I get an error message:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

The issue is `if exist dir1\*.*` always returns true, because there is `dir1\subdir`.

Is there a way to avoid this error message?

Comment: You don't need  the `If Exist` and to avoid the error message, redirect it to the NUL device: `Move /Y "dir1\*.*" "backup" 2>Nul`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a FOR command to iterate the files in the directory.  If there are no files in the directory then it will never execute the DO.

```
for %%G IN (dir1\*.*) do move "%%G" backup
```

One more option.

```
>nul 2>nul dir /a-d /b "dir1\*" && move dir1\*.* backup
```